# Ant replace property value by property name in a xml file

Tags: ant

I need to replace property value in a xml file using the property name.

Ex:

```
<property name="test-name" value="default-value"/>
```

I have a target to replace this value . i.e `"default-value"`. User can run this target several times if he's given a wrong value for property `test-name` he can try again running target with correct value. Therefore i can not use regular expression to replace `"default-value"`. I can only rely on property name. Is there a way to replace property value using it's name in ant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to allow the user to replace value multiple times ( if he/she given a wrong value) i came up with following solution,

```
           <replaceregexp
                    replace="property name=&quot;my.propertyKey&quot; 
                    value=&quot;user.value&quot;"
                    byline="true" file="${basedir}/test.xml">
                <regexp pattern="property name=&quot;my.property&quot; 
                    value=&quot;(.*)&quot;"/>
            </replaceregexp>
```

This searches property, using property key and replace entire line.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do that in Ant is to copy or move the files you want to change, using a [FilterSet](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) to define the token-value pairs you want to replace in the files.

So in your "template" version of the file you might have something like this

```
<document>
    <element value="@test-name@"/>
</document>
```

And in your build file you might have something like this:

```
<property name="my.value" value="default-value"/>
<copy file="${build.dir}/version.txt" toFile="${dist.dir}/version.txt" override="true">
  <filterset>
      <filter token="test-name" value="${my.value}"/>
  </filterset>
</copy>
```

Comment: It does not replace it in the original, it replaces it in the copy. If you use `override="true"` in the copy operation, then it is replaced every time with whatever the new value is.